# Java do not change value on interface after iterator stop it

Tags: java, iterator, label, jdialog

I have a problem with this.

I am doing a simple game to find a  number with JDialog. When I pressed "START" button, the number has to change it, but number does not change after iterator stop it.

```
boolean found = False;
Random random = new Random();


    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !found; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                int n = random.nextInt(10)+1;
                        lblNewLabel_1.setText(String.valueOf(n));

                if(n == numeroLoteria){
                        found = true;
                        System.out.println("Encontrado numero "+n+"!");
                }
                        System.out.println("Iteracion "+i+"\nnumero: "+n);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
    }
```

Label who has to change is lblNewLabel_1.

I want to change it in every iteration.

Comment: You blocked the EDT. Use `Timer` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Concurency In Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial from Oracle.

Couple key points

1. It's not recommended to access classes in `javax.swing.*` from any thread other than EDT.
2. Use a [javax.swing.SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)(Java 1.3 and beyond)  or [java.awt.SecondaryLoop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html) (Java 7 and beyond) for long running tasks which need to update or interact with your UI.  [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) can be used to fire events at a future time but should generally not be used for any long running tasks.

**EDIT** As mentioned in the comments you should not block the EDT.

Comment: SwingWorker added in Java 6 but otherwise +1

Comment: @dkatzel you are correct, SwingWorker was added to the JDK in 1.6 but it was widely available (though I believe unsupported) from Sun prior to the inclusion in the JDK.